# Concatenar con JS

Tags: javascript, html

Hola soy nuevo aqui y desearia que me ayudaran en un código de como concatenar html con javascript, este es mi codigo:

```
<ul>
    <li>objeto1</li>
    <li>objeto2</li>
    <li>objeto3</li>
    <li>objeto4</li>
</ul>
```

y necestio concatenar los li con un array en js como el siguiente

```
var frutas = [
      {
        'nombre'     : 'manzana',
        'indice' : 2
      },
      {
        'nombre'     : 'pera',
        'indice' : 4
      },
      {
        'nombre'     : 'durazno',
        'indice' : 1
      },
      {
        'nombre'     : 'fresa',
        'indice' : 3
      }
];
```

para que me muestre el indice mayor y el segundo mayor concatenado con los li de la lista, ejemplo:

Objeto 1, pera

Objeto 2, fresa

Espero que me puedan ayudar y de haberme explicado bien

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? Por favor leer [ask] y realizar el [tour]. Debes mostrar lo que hayas intentado, mostrando con claridad el problema o dificultad encontrada. Puedes leer [mcve] para mayor información. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) para ordenar el array, ya que es un array de objetos, vamos a ordenarlo dándole al método un *callback*, luego de ordenarlo, solo lo revertimos con [`Array.prototype.reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse), definimos una variable que irá aumentando, para poner el índice actual

```js
let frutas = [
      {
        'nombre'     : 'manzana',
        'indice' : 2
      },
      {
        'nombre'     : 'pera',
        'indice' : 4
      },
      {
        'nombre'     : 'durazno',
        'indice' : 1
      },
      {
        'nombre'     : 'fresa',
        'indice' : 3
      }
];

function orderUl(items) {
  items = (items.sort((a, b) => { 
    if (a.indice > b.indice) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.indice < b.indice) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  })).reverse();

  // Puedes hacer el sort() más corto:
  // items = (items.sort((a, b) => ((a.indice < b.indice)) ? -1 : ((a.indice > b.indice) ? 1 : 0))).reverse();
  
  let i = 1;
  items.forEach(el => {
    exampleUl.innerHTML += `<li>Objeto ${i}, ${el.nombre}</li>`;
    i++;
  });
}

orderUl(frutas);
```

```html
<ul id="exampleUl"></ul>
```

Comment: Todavía puedes hacer más corto el sort: `items = items.sort((a, b) => a.indice - b.indice).reverse();` y no es necesaria la variable `i`, porque en `forEach()` puedes agregar un segundo parámetro para obtener el índice.

Comment: Y, puedes evitar `reverse()` invirtiendo la operación: `items = items.sort((a, b) => b.indice - a.indice);`. De cualquier forma, es buena la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, fueron de gran ayuda

Comment: a que te refieres que no es necesario agregar i usando un segundo parámetro?